# Django Can i fill automatically list_display

Tags: python, django

I'm trying fill automatically my list_display on my admin Django, apparently the code works correctly, but it doesn't show nothing. This is my code

Model

```
class Pacient(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(
       max_length=50
   )
   last_name = models.CharField(
       max_length=50
   )
   id_identification = models.IntegerField()
   age= models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
   gender = models.ForeignKey(
       Gender,
       on_delete=models.CASCADE
   )
   blood_type = models.ForeignKey(
       BloodType,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
   )

   def __str__(self):
       return self.name
```

Admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Pacient


class PacientAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
 list_display=()
 x = Pacient.objects.values()

 def some(self):
   for k in self.x:
       k = k.keys()
       self.list_display=(tuple(k))
       print (self.list_display)   
   return self.list_display
   
admin.site.register(Pacient,PacientAdmin)
```

[image]

Comment: You never perform the `some` method...

Comment: put `some` in `list_display` like this: `list_display = ["some",]`.

Comment: @xtlc no, it didn't work

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem i don't get it, exactly in what part i should call it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call the `some` function in `list_display` - also the method of the class is used differently. This code snipped should work and show your `Pacient` data in the `list_display` and also "test" in every line:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Pacient

@admin.register(Pacient)
class PacientAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display=["name", "last_name", "age", "some",]

    def some(self, obj):
        return "test"
```

Comment: @xltc It works!!!, but i have a little question why i have to add other parameter in my method, in this case what's the use of parameter "obj" ?

Comment: just do `print(obj)` to see what is in there ... it is the current line of `Pacience`. You do not need `some` at all in your case, I just put it there to show you how you would call it since you used it in your code.

Comment: Thanks dude!! You're amazing, maybe we should share email or phone numbers haha